# java to scala to spark. NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have some scala utility classes for loading csv files and manipulating as DataFrames. They work fine from scala.

I just tried using the classes by invoking my scala util from java. I got the following exception.

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$DeprecatedConfig.(SparkConf.scala:723)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkConf$.(SparkConf.scala:571)

Both my java and scala projects are maven projects

My java application pom.xml just has one dependency, the dependency to my scala util.

My scala util initiates a SparkSession loads the csv files and manipulates the data in DataFrames. It has the following dependencies (which work fine when runningas standalone scala)

```xml
 <!---spark-->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-sql_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-streaming_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>

        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>

        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-graphx_2.11 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-graphx_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>

        </dependency>
```

Can someone offer a hint as to what I am missing

UPDATE: This is not a duplicate question.
Scala is not invoked directly in java. Even so I added a property to the java pom:

```
    <scala.version>2.11.11</scala.version>
```

This made no difference. The property is already in the scala pom

Comment: Please provide `mvn dependency:tree` result and version of the cluster you are using

Comment: Happy to oblige but needs trimming for space. Are you interested in scala, spark, both, or something more specific?

Comment: or maybe suggest what I should look for?

Comment: My intuition is that some other dependency may use other version of Scala and that's "bump" version to newer. Check `mvn dependency:tree | grep scala`

Comment: I have examined the tree and I'm not seeing that (My scala util is about the only top level in the tree). My intuition is that it is related to using a different JVM. Unfortunately, it is quicker to simply avoid calling the scala util from java than to debug....so it will remain a mystery until necessity demands I investigate

Comment: Do you use Spark-Submit or just launch via main methods?

Comment: I launch in the scala "construictor"
    val spark = SparkSession.builder()
      .master("local")
      .appName("TermsDataReduction")
      .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", "file:///c:/tmp/spark-warehouse")
      .getOrCreate()

Comment: Do you mean Scala REPL? Or just launching class with main function?

Comment: I am fairly new to scala, so maybe misunderstanding
The scala utility class is called instantiated from java. The instantiation of the scala class invokes the SparkSession. THis is where the exception occurs. So not a main method and, I think, not REPL

Comment: But do you deploy the application with Spark-Submit or just run it  from IDE?

Comment: maven calls junit which is calling java functions which calls scala function (still just unit testing)

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to be sure that Spark Submit version is not with other Scala version - but seems that is not relevant